# Why just boys in Maze Runner?

Tags: the-maze-runner

At the end of the Maze Runner 2014 film, we learn that:

> the maze trials were just an experiment to study brain activity under stressful conditions, so that a cure could be developed for an epidemic brain disease.

So why did they just use boys?

> We know that one girl showed up at the end, but she seemed to be an afterthought, escaping events in the control center.

I imagine that the answer may have been given in the books.

Answer (score 8):

This is explained in the second book (and presumably the second movie)

> There is a second maze, in which only girls lived. The events in both mazes were similar, both groups escaped at the same day. Also, the last person to enter the girls maze was a boy. (As Theresa entered the boys maze as last person). The Creators (of the maze) wanted to understand the difference of how The Flare attacks boys and girls, so they separated them (I can't find the quote from [The Death Cure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Cure) right now)

A hint to this is already given in the [first trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1AACTA7OtA) of the second movie, [The Scorch Trials](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4046784/?ref_=wl_li_tt)

Update (after having seen The Scorch Trials):

> The creators of the "Scorch Trials" movie changed a few things compared to the second book. In the second movie, it appears that there were multiple mazes (more than two). In the scenes in the cafeteria when all gladers have dinner, we can see other boys that were not in the "original" maze (with Thomas, Newt, etc).

Comment: @CodeMed: That answer would contain some heavy spoilers.